# PM2 unable to start process with uncaughtException in file

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, process, pm2

I have a server.js file. If i add

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

> App [server] with id [0] and pid [12648], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
>   PM2 > Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:server id:0                                                                              > PM2 > App name:server id:0 online                                                                                                                      > PM2 > Error caught while calling pidusage                                                                                                             > PM2 > Error: No maching pid found                                                                                                                      > PM2 >     at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pidusage\lib\wmic.js:51:21 
>   PM2 >     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pidusage\lib\bin.js:41:14)
>   PM2 >     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
>   PM2 >     at ChildProcess.emit (domain.js:439:23)
>   PM2 >     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
>   PM2 >     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
>    server > RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

somewhere in that file then by running command `pm2 start server.js` i get this error:

However if i remove exception handling server starts normally. 
Any ideas?

Comment: and are you able to run the server using node directly without use pm2? I guess you will have the same problem so paste the error after you test this please.

Comment: Yes I am able to run without pm2 without any problems

Comment: Oki, and what pm2 version and nodejs version are you using?

Comment: PM2 version is 3.0.4 and Nodejs is 9.8.0 but i tried also 10.x